# Does distance between charges affect potential difference?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, voltage, capacitance

does the distance between the + terminal and - terminal of a circuit affect the potential difference between the 2 points? given that the amount of charge remains constant.

for example if the terminals are connected with 20cm of wire, vs if the terminals are connected with 10cm of wire, will the latter circuit have a greater potential difference?

If the answer is yes, then why does potential difference decrease as electrons move across the wire? Wouldn't the reduced distance between the electron and the + terminal mean greater potential difference?

Answer (score 1):

The flaw in your question is the statement *given that the amount of charge remains constant*.

Assume that the two terminals of an ideal cell are the two plates of a capacitor with a potential difference across them equal to the emf of the cell.
Separating the plates will result in some charges flowing with the charge on the plates decreasing to a steady state value when the plates have stopped moving.
In this state the potential difference across the plates is now the same as it was before.

An electrochemical reaction within an ideal cell maintains a constant potential difference across its terminals.

With you two wires example, the potential difference across the ends of the two wires will not change but the current though them will be different.